# AccessDeniedException when deploying the lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to create the lambda function in aws through the AWS command.When I am executing the command, getting the below error. But the role which I've mentioned in the AWS command has enough permission in order to deploy the lambda function.I'm not sure what went wrong even though role has permission.

**Command:**

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name ukmon-appd-disabled- 
health-rules --runtime python3.7 --zip-file 
fileb://bin/disabled_health_rules.zip --handler index.handler --timeout 10 - 
-memory-size 1024 --role arn:aws:iam::99999999999:role/crossaccount
```

**Policies:**

```
"AllowLambdaFunctionStack": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "Description": "Policy for allowing jenkins cross account service role to create, update, delete lambda functions.",
        "Path": "/",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:DeleteFunction",
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:AddPermission",
                "lambda:RemovePermission",
                "lambda:CreateAlias",
                "lambda:DeleteAlias",
                "lambda:GetAlias",
                "lambda:ListAliases",
                "lambda:UpdateAlias",
                "lambda:GetPolicy",
                "lambda:InvokeAsync",
                "lambda:ListVersionsByFunction",
                "lambda:PublishVersion",
                "lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:GetEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
                "lambda:DeleteEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:UpdateEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:TagResource",
                "lambda:ListTags",
                "lambda:UntagResource"
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:999999999999:function:crossaccount-*",
              "Sid": "AllowLambdaFuctionsStacks"
            }
          ]
        },
```

**Error:**

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
>   CreateFunction operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::999999999999:assumed-role/crossaccount/i-0d2dd689c2784f174
>   is not authorized to perform: lambda:CreateFunction on resource:
>   arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:999999999999:function:ukmon-appd-disabled-health-rules

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are mixing up IAM roles in your question.  The IAM role you are passing to the `create-function` AWS CLI call is the role that the Lambda service will assume at runtime : i.e. the permissions you are giving to your lambda function at runtime.
To be authorised to make the `aws lambda create-function` CLI call, your environment must have the `CreateFunction` authorisation.

But in case you are not mixing up roles, there is a problem in your policy.  It  authorises all the listed API calls on Lambda resources complying to

`"Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:999999999999:function:crossaccount-*",`

The lambda function you're trying to create is named `ukmon-appd-disabled- 
health-rules` Only functions name starting with `crossaccount-` will be authorized.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same or pretty similar issue.

**The Problem**

My CodeBuild build was running fine until after a new change I got this error.

```
Error: error creating Lambda Function (1): AccessDeniedException: 

status code: 403, request id: 31ea35dd-7c9f-4911-94ef-7c8eaae58b66
with module.app.module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.this,
on ../../../libraries/zip_lambda/main.tf line 22, 
in resource "aws_lambda_function" "this":
```

Previous builds had gone well so clearly introducing this lambda broke the build.

Step 1 - Inspect the terraform plan

```
# module.app.module.lambda.aws_lambda_function. This will be created
  + resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
      + arn                            = (known after apply)
      + filename                       = "../../../libraries/zip_lambda/../../../out/lambdas/some-name.zip"
      + function_name                  = "some-name"
      + handler                        = "some-lambda-package/handler/handler.handler"
      + package_type                   = "Zip"
      + role                           = "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/LambdaExecution-some-lambda"
      + runtime                        = "python3.9"
      ...
      ...
      + vpc_config {
          + security_group_ids = [
              + "sg-some-sg-id",
            ]
          + subnet_ids         = [
              + "subnet-some-subnet-1-id",
              + "subnet-some-subnet-2-id",
            ]
          + vpc_id             = (known after apply)
        }
    }
```

The key thing was to realize that this lambda is trying to add a VPC configuration.

So I searched for `lambda in vpc security group permission`

And the first link took me to AWS' documentation: [Lambda's VPC Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html).
That is AWS Docs > Lambda > Managing Functions > Networking > Execution role and user permissions

```
When you configure VPC connectivity, Lambda uses your permissions to verify network resources. To configure a function to connect to a VPC, your AWS Identity, and Access Management (IAM) user needs the following permissions:

User permissions
    ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups
    ec2:DescribeSubnets
    ec2:DescribeVpcs
```

**The solution**

Add these permissions to the Role CodeBuild assumes to build and deploy the infrastructure described in Terraform.

```
ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups
ec2:DescribeSubnets
ec2:DescribeVpcs
```

**Note**

It's important to note AccessDeniedException it's because the service or user deploying is lacking enough permissions. Which is not related to permissions assigned to the Lambda role.

The IAM Role used by my lambda `role/LambdaExecution-some-lambda` is pretty much the one in [AWS Lambda's Developer Guide documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)

Policy permissions

```
permissions = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
  "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSXRayDaemonWriteAccess"]
```

Assume Role policy

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    sid     = "LambdaRole"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect  = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started getting the error after I tried to change aws region for my whole infrastructure.
Issue was that I didn't change lambda layers' region which was hardcoded in the layer arn

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same mistake.
I forgot to inform AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

Answer (score -1):

Click `Add Permissions` at `IAM > User groups` page.
I added these policies:

```
AWSCodeDeployRoleForLambda
AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
AWSLambdaRole
AWSLambdaMSKExecutionRole
AWSLambda_FullAccess
```

I don't know what policy exactly makes it work.

Comment: Giving full access is never a good idea. Consider least privilege access